# postgresql partition by list with non primary key not working - insufficient columns in PRIMARY KEY constraint definition

Tags: postgresql, list, partition

create table employeedata(
id varchar(20) primary key,
department varchar(20),
salary integer,
designation varchar(20)
) partition by list (department);

but i am getting following error

ERROR:  insufficient columns in PRIMARY KEY constraint definition
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "employeedata" lacks column "department" which is part of the partition key.
SQL state: 0A000

Am i doing anything wrong please help

I want to create table  employee data  and partition by departement column
so i can get all employee of particular department in partition

Comment: Make department part of the key like the error message tells you? Then read the manuals so you know what you are doing. Also - please tell me this isn't actually employees and departments, in the real database you have hundreds of millions of rows, yes?

Comment: but this concept works if we inherit table why not partition